# How to mock JSON import Jest TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I want to mock a .json file using Jest for unit testing in Typescript.

I'm currently using this global mock inside jest.config.js file. And this is working fine:

```
    'package.json': '<rootDir>/__tests__/tasks/__mocks__/data.json'
```

But I want to mock it locally, inside my test class.

This didn't work for me:

```
jest.mock('../../package.json', () => ({
    package : { name: '__name__', 'version': '__version__'};
}), { virtual: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

have you try the following?

```js
const packageJson = require('../../package.json);
 jest.mock(packageJson, () => ({
     package : { name: '__name__', 'version': '__version__'};
 }), { virtual: true })
```

Comment: Else try es6 import statement

Comment: thank you for your reply. But still not woking. Function is woking as default, without mocked values.